# Where does AzureAD store the "id" attribute returned by a SCIM endpoint?

Tags: azure-active-directory, scim

I am integrating AzureAD with a SCIM endpoint. So far integration seems to work: AzureAD sends "POST" requests to create users, then later it queries/updates users using their 'id'.

Reminder from SCIM standard (RFC 7643): The 'id' is

> A unique identifier for a SCIM resource as defined by the service provider

My SCIM endpoint generates this unique ID upon user first creation. It sends this ID to AzureAD in the reply, as required by the standard. I know that AzureAD stores the ID somewhere, because it uses it in subsequent requests.

My question: where is this ID stored in AzureAD? I need to read it, so I can forward it somewhere else. Using Graph Explorer I tried a lot of properties:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me?$select=id,userPrincipalName,extensions,employeeId,externalUserState,identities,externalId
```

But none of them work. They are empty or do not contain the SCIM id.

Does anyone know if the property is publicly available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure AD Provisioning has an internal data store that is not exposed via any external/customer-facing APIs where this is stored. If the service is evaluating an object that it does not know the SCIM ID value for it will try to locate that using a filtered GET such as GET /Users?filter=userName eq "user@domain.com", but once it has located that object the service will store internally a record stating that object X in Azure AD with objectId value of 123 is matched to object Y in  with ID value of 456.

To specifically answer your end goal of "I need to find this value in Azure AD and forward it somewhere else" - this is not possible.

Comment: What I'm wondering is, what is the best practice to correlate SCIM-provisioned users and Azure AD OAuth logins? It seems that there is no unique ID (objectid) that is shared between SCIM and OAuth. The most straightforward option would be to use the UPN, but as SCIM might have a delay of up to 40 minutes (or more, if something doesn't work), isn't that a security risk?

Answer (score 0):

It is not like you think that AAD will save the user id from SCIM.

You can use [Provision on demand](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/app-provisioning/provision-on-demand#understand-the-provisioning-steps) to understand how it works.

Simple steps:

Click on "Provision on demand" in SCIM enterprise app.

[image]

Then select an AAD user and click on "Provision".

After it is executed successfully, you will be able to see the following:

[image]

**Import user** is retrieving User from Azure Active Directory.

**Determine if user is in scope** is determining if User in scope by evaluating against each scoping filter.

**Match user between source and target system** is retrieving User from SCIM and matching it with the AAD User in step 1. This is the **point** that you didn't know before. AAD will [Get User by query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/app-provisioning/use-scim-to-provision-users-and-groups#get-user-by-query) in this step.

```
GET /Users?filter=userName eq "{userName}"
```

Then the user id from SCIM will be returned (As above screenshot shows).

**Perform action** updates User in SCIM using the id from step 3.

So AAD doesn't store the id from SCIM. It queries the user in SCIM firstly to get the id and then use this id to send update request to SCIM endpoint.